# How to delete post build tangling docker images from Jenkins build file or bash script?

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

In a Jenkins pipeline scenario, how can I delete the images which are remaining after the build?

I am now login on the VM and using a manual command:

```
 docker images -q |xargs docker rmi
```

This is my Jenkins script:

```
        stage 'Deploy'
         dir('/apps/npt'){
            sh 'chmod +x deploy_prod.sh'
            sh './deploy_prod.sh'
         }
```

This is the deploy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#build docker container
docker build -t nptproduction .


# stop existing container and remove image
docker stop nptproduction && docker rm nptproduction

# run new image
docker run  -d -p 5021:4000  --name nptproduction nptproduction
```

I know that in the deploy script I would need to catch any errors and if so, do not stop / not delete the existing (working images / container), but this is subject to a future update...

Answer (score 1):

(I am assuming you require assistance from the jenkins point of view.)

If you are using a Declarative pipeline syntax in your jenkinsfile, you can add your remove command in the post section. You can add the directive as always or on success depending on your use case:

```
post { 
        success { 
            sh ''
        }
    }
```

In the above sh'' statement, you can use the command to remove all the docker images except for the ones required.
URL: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions

Comment: thanks so much! actually I would need support on how to actually delete the images themselves as well. ...